# Fonts for personal use

Tags: fonts

Can I use fonts from da fonts that are used for personal use in edits to post on tiktok? I don't make any money, so would it be okay for me to use it. I found a lot of cute fonts on da fonts that I would like to use in edits. So can I use personal use fonts for TikTok, or is that not okay.

Comment: Theoretically they allow many fonts free for pwrsonal use. But you never know when one of the font owner changes his mind and report your tiktok video for using his font.

Comment: I once used a free for personal use audio on my instagram. The owner had written free for personal use anywhere and credit not needed. But a few days later the audio in my video got muted. After that I started taking such things more seriously.

Comment: Publishing anywhere, even FB, Instagram, TokTok etc is no longer 'personal use'. It's published, out there for the world to see.

Comment: This is *actually* a legal question. Whether or not *you* usage constitutes "personal use" would need to be determined by a judge or arbiter should you feel you're within the license but the license holder feels you are not. -- I do agree with @Tetsujin personally, once you publish something using the font *anywhere* it's no longer "personal use." The fact that *your* social media account may not make money is irrelevant.

Comment: Personal use does not mean in general if i do it myself. Because otherwise a big part of commercial scale operation would disqualify because its indistinguishable  from doing for my self. Nor is getting money from things a good qualifier either because then all internal/tool and prep use use would be noncommercial. But rather it means if you only use it in your immediate close circles, in which case posting on a global marketplace of ideas does not qualify.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to check the description every time, but I remember most fonts on Dafont do mention free personal usage.

Commercial usage limited or paid in most cases.